# How can I use angular-supported library in React?

Tags: angular, reactjs, cron

I find difficulty in using (['cron-editor'](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron-editor)) library  in my React project. What can I do after installing it by `npm i cron-editor`?
The following is a guide using in Angular application but what I want is to use it in React:

> 1. Import the module in your own module:

```
      import { CronEditorModule } from "cron-editor";
 

      @NgModule({
         imports: [..., CronEditorModule],
       ...
      })
      export class MyModule {
      }
```

> 2. Use the component in your html code:
>
>    `<cron-editor [(cron)]="cronExpression"></cron-editor>`
> 3. That's it, you're done!

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: not, its a library for Angular specific as far as i know.

Comment: I think this answer related to reactjs more than angular maybe you need to remove the angular tag 

Comment: try to use npm install --save react-cron-builder

Comment: ah yeah..my mistake..I just thought I have added the angular tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am pretty sure you cant.

"cron-editor is library that helps the user graphically build a CRON expression (quartz format only) in an Angular application. It is a fork of angular-cron-gen for AngularJS, ported to Angular 2+ and heavily improved."

Am pretty sure its Angular specific.

Comment: I have read some articles about using angular components in react, such as: https://medium.com/appifycanada/angular-components-in-react-2c929130f995. Do you think it will work?

Comment: this is a way to make a specific route to run React App instead of the Angular App. As far as I have read articles you can use them side by side, but you cant use an React component inside an Angular component and vice versa.

But again, thats all I could find. If you think about it, they compile the code different with different features. So it would be really weird that an Angular compiler could compile an React Component.

Comment: tbh, I think its way cleaner and easyer to just find a react component for you project. You choose for React, so stay with React. Don't make it dirty.

Comment: here is one for example, looks pretty good: https://github.com/liudongrong/cron-editor